# How to get average starting third previous record to be included to current row as column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have some data like below:

| id | date | code | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 892 | 2022-02-04 | B | 472 |
| 891 | 2022-02-03 | B | 58 |
| 890 | 2022-02-02 | B | 467 |
| 868 | 2022-01-28 | B | 50 |
| 821 | 2022-01-23 | B | 45 |
| 780 | 2022-01-20 | B | 55 |
| 550 | 2022-01-14 | B | 79 |
| 245 | 2022-01-12 | B | 841 |
| 112 | 2022-01-11 | B | 128 |
| 91 | 2022-01-07 | B | 174 |
| 74 | 2022-01-04 | B | 64 |

I want to get the average price of three records, starting from previous third row to be included to current row in one SQL query, so I'm expecting like below:

| id | date | code | price | avg3th |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 892 | 2022-02-04 | B | 472 | average of ( 467+50+45) |
| 891 | 2022-02-03 | B | 58 | average of ( 50+45+55) |
| 890 | 2022-02-02 | B | 467 | average of ( 50+45+79) |
| 868 | 2022-01-28 | B | 50 | average of ( 45+79+841) |
| 821 | 2022-01-23 | B | 45 | average of ( 79+841+128) |
| 780 | 2022-01-20 | B | 55 | average of ( 841+128+174) |
| 550 | 2022-01-14 | B | 79 | ... |
| 245 | 2022-01-12 | B | 841 | ... |
| 112 | 2022-01-11 | B | 128 | ... |
| 91 | 2022-01-07 | B | 174 | ... |
| 74 | 2022-01-04 | B | 64 | ... |

What I have tried, using below query:

```
SELECT t.id, t.date, t.code, t.price,
format(
 CASE WHEN
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.date) >=5 THEN
         AVG ( t.price ) OVER (ORDER BY t.date
            ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING)
    ELSE NULL
 END,0) AS average_3th
FROM test t ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

However, above the query still includes the first element as average (it should begin at third element), so the below result still wrong:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: It would be good if your desired outcome was based on your sample data or you explained why the ids are so different and if you showed the averages,

Comment: @P.Salmon i have fixed it

Comment: So you want to calculate the average of rows between 4 preceding and 2 preceding? Your expected result does that so should your AVG windows

Comment: I want to calculate the average of 3 rows starting of previous 3rd row into current row, i have tried finding this solution on SO but still not found similiar issue

Comment: Images of data discourage answers because it forces us to transcribe rather than copy and paste,,

Comment: @P.Salmon okay, i will fix it, please wait...

Comment: Did you check my answer - I don't see a comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the row number idea average in a sub query

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT T.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY ID DESC) RN FROM T ),
CTE1 AS
(SELECT T.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY ID DESC) RN FROM T )
SELECT CTE.*,
         (SELECT AVG(CTE1.PRICE) FROM CTE1 WHERE CTE1.CODE = CTE.CODE AND CTE1.RN BETWEEN CTE.RN + 2 AND CTE.RN + 4),
          (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CTE1.ID) FROM CTE1 WHERE CTE1.CODE = CTE.CODE AND CTE1.RN BETWEEN CTE.RN + 2 AND CTE.RN + 4)
FROM CTE
ORDER BY CTE.ID DESC
;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=437342579b3165f31292e288e3165bed

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer :) however, after which position then i can place your sql code "with cte...."

Comment: Replace all your code with this code..

Comment: I got this error in phpmyadmin : `Unrecognized statement type. (near "WITH" at position 0)`

Comment: What do get as a result from select version();

Comment: 8.0.28, query get red warning, but now i can get result. i will accept your answer.